# "It's taking me forever" vs "It has been taking me forever"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, progressive-aspect

If you are writing a long report, which one sounds more natural: "Oh, this report is so long, it's taking me forever" or "Oh, this report is so long, it has been taking me forever"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed they are both correct. The second, however, with its backwards looking present perfect, suggests the implication that from this point forward, it might not be such a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and natural. Compare:

It's two years since I last saw Jack.

It's been two years since I last saw Jack.

Comment: If it's been two years, I suggest you purchase a mirror.

Comment: Evidently, the subject of the sentence (I) is not the same as the object (Jack).